# Alias and Redirect in same Apache vhost

Tags: apache-2.4

I have configuration like this.

I want /.well-known/acme-challenge/ to work without redirect, but everything else to go to https:// example.com

Already tried with  but it also does not work.

```
<VirtualHost _default_>
    ServerName     example.com

    Alias       /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/

    Redirect    /   https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You could re-write only if the requested file doesn't exist... and leave the letsencrypt stuff as the only files that do exist.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595005/redirect-requests-only-if-the-file-is-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with RewriteEngine:

```
<VirtualHost _default_>
   ServerName example.com
   Alias    /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/

   RewriteEngine    On
   RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/
   RewriteRule  /(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```